# Primary TEL, EMAIL and etc properties in VCard

Tags: java, android, contacts, vcf-vcard

I'm working on contacts exchange and sync framework for Android mobiles.

I need to transform the data from Android ContactsContract.Data table to VCard and vice versa.

So, it will be possible to export and import contacts in VCard format.

I decided to use [EZVCard](https://code.google.com/p/ez-vcard/) library for parsing and formatting VCards.

Android ContactsContract.Data table has IS_PRIMARY column. 
In rfc6350 (VCard standard) i found nothing about primary properties.

Is there standard way to mark a property in VCard as primary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With vCard 3, you would use a TYPE=pref parameter (e.g. `TEL;TYPE=HOME,PREF:+12`) whereas with vCard 4, you can use a PREF=1 parameter (e.g. `TEL;VALUE=uri;PREF=1;TYPE="voice,home":tel:+1-555-555-5555;ext=5555`)